# Name convention to method for primitive vs nullable results

Tags: java, primitive-types

Is there some name convention for methods that returns primitive vs nullable ones?

Example:

```
public double getDouble() {
    //...
}

public Double getDouble() {
    //...
}
```

I want to have both of these methods in my project, but I can't figure out what would be a good name for the `Double` one. I have the same problem with the `getShort` and `getInteger` methods.

Edit:

I think some of you guys misunderstood me.
Those examples are just a part of my code to simplify my question.
They are part of a class that can return the value of a string in several ways, getShort, getInt, getDouble etc.
In some cases we need the nullable one and in other one we need the primitive one.

There are some reasons that can justify this approach like usability for the team's members and use cases where which method would be called around my code

Comment: You don't need to add the return type in the method name, it's already indicated **in the return type**. All IDEs are able to show the return type of the method, so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: If you have a method that returns a primitive, it stands to reason you can never return null, so you don’t need the second method.

Comment: There is no naming convention for this, so make your own. I've used `double getDouble()` vs `Double getDoubleObj()` in the past, but you could also use `Double getBoxedDouble()` or `Double getNullableDouble()`. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: guys, please, see my edit note. @Andreas thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Consider using `java.util.OptionalDouble` instead of a boxed nullable `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no naming convention, it should be documented in the API of the corresponding function. Every method that returns an object can return `null` in principle.

Since Java 8 there is a class [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) that can be used to avoid a `null` return value, making the program safer.

```
   public Optional<Double> getSomething() {
       return Optional.ofNullable(something);
   }
```

The caller will be able to test if there is a value with `isPresent()`, or use a lambda to process it with `ifPresent(value -> ....)`.

However, nothing in Java will force you to use `Optional`, nor is there a naming convention.

Answer (score -1):

You are not supposed to use class name or type to form the getter or setter.

You should use the object's name or variable's name.

eg. for `Double length;` the getter would be `getLength()`

If you want both, you may use something like:

```
public double getLength(){
    return length;
}

public Double getLengthNullable{
    //return sth
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will edit my question to clarify some points